# YouTube video stop working when play in video view

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am working in android application using android studio. 
The you tube video show in video view but when start playing video it just play small part of video then stop work and I need to press play button to play smart part then stop work again and so on.
How can the video plat till end?
my code:
    YouTubePlayerFragment myYoutubeFragment;

```
Button button;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;*/


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_song);

    myYoutubeFragment=(YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubePlayerFragment);
    myYoutubeFragment.initialize(API_KEY,this);

}
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason)
{
    if(errorReason.isUserRecoverableError())
    {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    }
    else
        {
            String errorMessage= String.format("Error in youtube",errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored)
{
    //start buffering
    if(!wasRestored)
    {
        player.cuePlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID);

    }

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST )
    {
        //retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(API_KEY,this);
    }


}
protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider()
{
    return (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerFragment);
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    myYoutubeFragment.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    myYoutubeFragment.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. I recommend you to add the error that you got then the app crashes.

Comment: Thanks, no error show to me while compiling but when testing the code. I post all code because I do not Know where the problem exactly.